# Spark: Add column with map logic without using UDF

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Basically, I want to apply my function **countSimilarColumns** on each row of dataframe and put the result in a new column.

My code is as follows

```
def main(args: Array[String]) = {
    val customerID           = "customer-1" //args(0)
    val rawData              = readFromResource("json", "/spark-test-data-copy.json")
    val flattenData          = rawData.select(flattenSchema(rawData.schema): _*)
    val referenceCustomerRow = flattenData.transform(getCustomer(customerID)).first
  }

def getCustomer(customerID: String)(dataFrame: DataFrame) = {
    dataFrame.filter($"customer" === customerID)
  }

def countSimilarColumns(first: Row, second: Row): Int = {
    if (!(first.getAs[String]("customer").equals(second.getAs[String]("customer"))))
      first.toSeq.zip(second.toSeq).count { case (x, y) => x == y }
    else
      -1
  }
```

I want to do something like follows. But I don't know how to do it.

```
flattenData
  .withColumn(
    "similarity_score",
    flattenData.map(row => countSimilarColumns(row, referenceCustomerRow))
  )
  .show()
```

**Sample data Flattened:**

```
{"customer":"customer-1","att-a":"7","att-b":"3","att-c":"10","att-d":"10"}
{"customer":"customer-2","att-a":"9","att-b":"7","att-c":"12","att-d":"4"}
{"customer":"customer-3","att-a":"7","att-b":"3","att-c":"1","att-d":"10"}
{"customer":"customer-4","att-a":"9","att-b":"14","att-c":"10","att-d":"4"}
```

**desired output:**

```
+--------------------+-----------+
| customer   | similarity_score |
+--------------------+-----------+
|customer-1  |  -1    | 
|customer-2  |  0    |
|customer-3  |  3    |
|customer-4  |  1    |
```

Is **UDF** the only way? and if yes, then I want to keep my function **countSimilarColumns** as it is so it is testable. How's it possible?
Im new to Spark/Scala.

Comment: how are you assigning similarity score , do you have any logic ?, let say if customer-3 has repeated 10 times, are you adding 10 as similarity score ?

Comment: I have added the function countSimilarColumns when I posted it. It result in the similarity_score for that row. the function checks if the values of two columns are the same then count++.  I just need to put in in a new column in a DF.

Comment: correct me if it is wrong, lets say if customer column has value customer-3 5 times that means count for customer-3 - 5 .. is it correct ?

Comment: wrong! what you're saying is a simple count() on a cloumn of dataframe. I compare two rows not columns. and a row can have x number of coulmns so compare each indexed column and then count if they are same.

Comment: in simple words, I want to apply my function countSimilarColumns on each row of dataframe and put the result in a new column

Comment: so you want to compare complete row with subsequent rows ? if it matches you are incrementing the count.. ?

Comment: Instead of comparing column by column .. can we convert all columns to json string & use window count functions on that columns.. if string matches multiple times count will increases .. will that work ?

Comment: nope! I count how many columns in two rows match and I have already done that, If you're able to follow through the code. Just need to add this result to a new column.

Comment: one last , your sample data & required output is not matching .. in your input customer column has customer-1, customer-2, customer-3, customer-4 & output has different values.. ? how it came ??

Comment: its just sample data. Im not going to post 100k rows here. and the output is also a sample.

Comment: we can discuss your idea sure. Why do you think that's better? But this(counting) was not my question. my question was to add the functions result to a new column.
like applying a UDF to row instead of a column.

Comment: what i am asking is if you can match sample input & output .. it is easy to understand & implement ..

Comment: flattenData.map(row => countSimilarColumns(row, referenceCustomerRow)) this will return DF, I think its not possible to put DF inside DF column. one thing is you have to collect result ,add it to DF. like this - flattenData.withColumn("similarity_score",lit(flattenData.map(row => countSimilarColumns(row, referenceCustomerRow)).collect.map(_.toInt)))  & problem is it will keep same result [-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1] for all rows.

Comment: I understand that I would return a fixed result but If it works on the underlying map_reduce properly it should be fine.

Comment: can you tell me how you got this from the above sample data  - |customer-1  |  -1    |  ? it should be |customer-1  |  3    | is it correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to fully understand that all the standard, non-aggregate operations on DF only see one line at a time. So, you have to think in terms of either 1 row or an aggregate. Calling function on a whole DF within single row context - your `withColumn` call is very unusual. When you want to compare/combine row to other rows you usually join table to another table or to itself and then work with the combined table.

What you want is something along those lines

```
// create DF with similarity scores AND customer, which is treated as row id here
val similarityDF = flattenData.map(row => row.getAs[String]("customer") -> countSimilarColumns(row, referenceCustomerRow)).
                   toDF("customer","similarity_score")

// join your original DF with similarityDF based on "customer"
flattenData.join(simlarityDF, usingColumn = "customer").show()
```

this allows you to match lines of the two DFs.

UDF is not really applicable here because UDF, similarly to built-in functions, is applied to one (or several) specific columns to produce a value (which can be added as a column using `withColumn`), where you want to look at the whole Row.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed. I had two things in mind. Either to JOIN or somehow to add the dataset which i get from countSimilarColumns to the flattenDataDF But i was unable to do both.  I'm new to spark and scala so my skills are limited. 
Could you explain this syntax ```row.getAs[String]("customer") ->``` how it is turned into two columns (this is what i was missing all along).  

secondly, can i rename the columns in the same step? as the names of the columns are shown _1 and _2 in similarityDF. I dont need a join as i dont need the attributes. 
Thanks!!!

Comment: I was able to do it by adding ```.toDF(Seq("customer", "similarity_score"): _*)``` at the end. is this a ok way to do in spark?

Comment: @Sam  `a -> b` is equivalent to `(a,b)` - it's just syntactic sugar for tuple, so `map` produces RDD of tuples, which is then converted to DataFrame with `toDF`. You rename the columns inside `toDF`. `.toDF(Seq("customer", "similarity_score"): _*)` is OK but unnecessary - the `:_*` syntax is used to pass Seq to function with variadic arguments. However, since you know what you want to pass `toDF("customer", "similarity_score")` is simpler and more readable.

Comment: understood, Thanks!  Another question. when I to do ```row.getAs[String]("customer")->``` it ask for implicit conversation(Encoder). I heard implicit conversions aren't so efficient and optimized. if so it there another way to do without implicit conversion?

Answer (score 0):

`flattenData` is of type `DataFrame` & applying map function on flattenData will get result of `Dataset`.

You are passing result of `flattenData.map(row => countSimilarColumns(row, referenceCustomerRow))` to `withColumn` but `withColumn` can only take the data of type `org.apache.spark.sql.Column`

So if you want to add above result without `UDF` to a column you have to use `collect` function & then pass it to `lit`

Please check below code.

```
flattenData
.withColumn("similarity_score",lit(
        flattenData
        .map(row => countSimilarColumns(row, referenceCustomerRow))
        .collect
        .map(_.toInt)
   )
)
```

**Based on sample data, Added below logic.**

```
scala> df.show(false)
+-----+-----+-----+-----+----------+
|att-a|att-b|att-c|att-d|customer  |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+----------+
|7    |3    |10   |10   |customer-1|
|9    |7    |12   |4    |customer-2|
|7    |3    |1    |10   |customer-3|
|9    |14   |10   |4    |customer-4|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+----------+


scala> val conditions = df.columns.filterNot(_ == "customer").map(c => (when(count(col(c)).over(Window.partitionBy(col(c)).orderBy(col(c).asc)) =!= 1,lit(1)).otherwise(0))).reduce(_ + _) // if row_number is 1 then adding 1 else 0 ..
conditions: org.apache.spark.sql.Column = (((CASE WHEN (NOT (count(att-a) OVER (PARTITION BY att-a ORDER BY att-a ASC NULLS FIRST unspecifiedframe$()) = 1)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END + CASE WHEN (NOT (count(att-b) OVER (PARTITION BY att-b ORDER BY att-b ASC NULLS FIRST unspecifiedframe$()) = 1)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + CASE WHEN (NOT (count(att-c) OVER (PARTITION BY att-c ORDER BY att-c ASC NULLS FIRST unspecifiedframe$()) = 1)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) + CASE WHEN (NOT (count(att-d) OVER (PARTITION BY att-d ORDER BY att-d ASC NULLS FIRST unspecifiedframe$()) = 1)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

**Final Result**

```
scala> df.withColumn("similarity_score",conditions).show(false)
+-----+-----+-----+-----+----------+----------------+
|att-a|att-b|att-c|att-d|customer  |similarity_score|
+-----+-----+-----+-----+----------+----------------+
|9    |7    |12   |4    |customer-2|2               |
|7    |3    |1    |10   |customer-3|3               |
|7    |3    |10   |10   |customer-1|4               |
|9    |14   |10   |4    |customer-4|3               |
+-----+-----+-----+-----+----------+----------------+
```

Comment: would a UDF be a better choice here? if yes, then how to pas row to UDF. because the examples I've seen only do operation on a column, and here the columns can be more than a few. hardcoding wouldn't be nice

Comment: I think no.. my question is the result u got from method how are you going to map corresponding row or column ?

Comment: that I also dont know. Thats why I asked the question because what I had in mind was. 
You compare columns of two rows and return a Int and that Int is added as value to the new column for that row which is being passed to the function. 
but it returns the result after doing the calculation on all data. so I'm there again its not kinda useful

Comment: To be frank I have not understood your expected output.. if possible please take sample data with 4 columns and show all possible output and include all columns.. sorry for asking again..

Comment: if i just run ```val similarity_scores    = flattenData.map(row => countSimilarColumns(row, referenceCustomerRow))```. it gives me a dataset with the scores.
im thinking to add this(scores) to another dataframe to get the desired output.
maybe this is the easier way. But im unsure as theres nothing to join on or if zip the two (flatenned and the score) maybe the result isn't the same due to unidentical partitioning.

Comment: I have updated answer, Based on my understanding I came up with this logic.. let me know if its not working ?

Comment: but this not hte correct similarity score. its not the same as the output. ?
e.g. customer 1 and customer 3 have 3 values that are same so it should be 3

Comment: I think now I have got correct result .. check again, customer 1 has 4 values 7 , customer 3 has 3 values ?

Comment: the score column i posed in the output has the correct values. customer-4 has score 1 but in your case its 3. Also, customer-1 has -1 as its the customer we're comparing against so -1 just to neglect it while sorting.

Comment: how customer 4 has 3 matching values for columns att-a, att-c & att-d how come its value is 1 ,can you explain ?

Comment: customer 4 has only 1 matching value. how it has 3 matching?

Comment: ```val similarity_scores = flattenData.map(row => countSimilarColumns(row, referenceCustomerRow))```
I pass a referencecustomer. in this case customer-1. So each row is matched with customer-1 thats why i assign it -1 to ignore it. I have written it in the post as well. 
so if you match customer-4 with customer-1 only 1 value matches hence score = 1

Comment: what I'm overall trying to do is find topN similar customers for a given customer.

Comment: are you not comparing row with sub sequent rows ?

Comment: 1 reference row(which the user gives from commandline) with other rows. What you're doing is compare every row with every row.

Comment: yes, exactly i am comparing one row with other rows.. how user will give you from command line if you have more number of columns ?

Comment: the user only gives the customerID ofcourse it doesnt give whole row. its written in the post.

Comment: check the main and getCustomer functions. i get the row from customerID

Comment: you're not taking a reference row to compare with other rows. 

You take one row at a time and compare it with whole dataset and if whole dataset has matching values you increment the count. this is not the intended behaviour

Comment: look at the desired output. you'll understand. each row is matched agaist curstomer-1 which was given from commandline